# how to add new items to recyclerview without scroll to top

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to set new items to top of recyclerview. But when I set items, recyclerview scroll to top automatically.
I tried many codes but I can't resolve that.
here is my `addItem` method:

```
   public void addItem(final ArrayList<String> list) {


    for (int i=0; i< list.size();i++){
        items.add(i,list.get(i));
    }
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
//                notifyItemRangeInserted( 0,list.size() );
//                notifyItemInserted();

            notifyItemRangeInserted(10,11);
//                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });




}
```

I tried all of commented method.
could you please help me to resolve this??
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finaly I got a solution. I put `notifyItemRangeChanged` after set new Items. my solution is:

```
 public void addItem(final ArrayList<String> list,int h) {

    final int oldsize = items.size();
    for (int i=list.size()-1; i>=0 ;i--){
        items.add(0,list.get(i));
    }

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(0,items.size()-oldsize);
        }
    });

}
```

I hope this is been useful for everyone. Thanks

Comment: Why the `activity.runOnUiThread` part? Don't you do this in the UI thread already? If it's not on the UI thread, you could theoratically have multi-threads issues, because `list` is used in both threads

Answer (score 0):

You can use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);` where pos is position where you want to focus your listview at after some operation on list.

Comment: my question is about `recyclerView`. not about `listView`

Comment: similar mehtod is there for recyclerview as well, wait I will edit the answer

Comment: you can use scrollToPosition() method for recycler view which works like setSelection() method of listview